# Is an email verified in AzureAD

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

When using AzureAD authentication for a web app or a native app is it possible to determine if the user's email is verified?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a property for it in AAD. If the user is an AAD user, the domain has been verified (or is something.onmicrosoft.com).

If the user is an external user with a Microsoft account, then the MS account signup process has verified the e-mail, but in general, I don't think that you can be sure of it.